# server doesn't work when I run it in jar

Tags: java, jar

I've got simple class which runs some `Main` class from some `.jar` file.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    org.runner.Main.main(args);
}
}
```

But when I run via Eclipse or other IDE - it works fine. And in IDE console it shows

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\xultestapplication\Test\bin\myapp
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\xultestapplication\Test\bin\myapp\defaults
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\xultestapplication\Test\bin\myapp\chrome
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\xultestapplication\Test\bin\myapp\chrome\content
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\xultestapplication\Test\bin\myapp\defaults\preferences
server started!
org.runner.Calculator.calculator:org.runner.Calculator|calculator
Sent with code 200
```

where `sent with code 200` means that it successfully sent response to client.
But when I run it in cmd `java -jar test.jar` - it doesn't work and

```
H:\disk\EXE>java -jar test.jar
H:\disk\EXE\bin\myapp
H:\disk\EXE\bin\myapp\defaults
H:\disk\EXE\bin\myapp\chrome
H:\disk\EXE\bin\myapp\chrome\content
H:\disk\EXE\bin\myapp\defaults\preferences
server started!
Sent with code 404
```

the result code is 404.

What is the problem?

Comment: An unknown client sends an unknown request to an unknown server and receives a 404. How could we help?

Comment: Please provide more detail on how the server decides whether to return 200 or 404.

Comment: The problem is that it works fine when I run project in IDE. But when I export project as `runnable jar file` and then run JAR - it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm. Via eclipse it prints out `org.runner.Calculator.calculator:org.runner.Calculator|calculator`. This line isn't printed out by the jar. Just my guess: are you sure that your jar is updated?

Comment: Well it shows because in jar within package `org.runner` (it is in build path of `test` project) there is this `Calculator` class.

Comment: There are several possiblities. For example, your server tries to return certain file based on client's request. But, the server determines the location of this file relative to the directory where the code is executed. If you use IDE, the directory may be `/home/workspace/helloworld`, where as if you use `java -jar` the directory may be `/home`. We really need to see the code to be certain.

Comment: Yes it works. I moved my pages from `bin` to folder with jar and it started to work fine

Comment: @user1432980 Great. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the server is automatically run from within your Eclipse environment?
If this is the case, you must of course make sure it is also run when starting your test outside Eclipse.

Comment: Well I start it in my `org.runner.Main` class.

Comment: This line is not printed out when the result code is 404: `org.runner.Calculator.calculator:org.runner.Calculator|calculator`.

Perhaps some error occurs inside the server, which is not printed out. For example if you try-catch an Exception that is not printed out into the console using e.g. ex.printStackTrace().